# AWK - moving fields (corrected version)

Tags: awk

I have a file:

```
A B C D E
jeden dwa- trzy cztery piec
czarny) bialy zielony niebieski siwy
czarny) bialy zielony niebieski siwy
kot pies mysz osa byk
jeblon grusza czeresnia- sliwa orzech
tulipan narcyz filolek) irys bez
sliwka jabkko pomarancza kiwi arbuz
5 A B C D E
sliwka jabkko pomarancza kiwi arbuz-
marek ewa ela tomek) romek
```

I have tried:

```
awk 'c-->0;/- /{c=1; print}' file
```

How to improve this example, to obtain such a result?
I want to get this result:

```
A B C D E
jeden dwa-czarny) trzy cztery piec
 bialy zielony niebieski siwy
czarny) bialy zielony niebieski siwy
kot pies mysz osa byk
jeblon grusza czeresnia-filolek) sliwa orzech
tulipan narcyz  irys bez
sliwka jabkko pomarancza kiwi arbuz
5 A B C D E
sliwka jabkko pomarancza kiwi arbuz-tomek)
marek ewa ela  romek
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What if you explain the logic behind it? Polish is not that easy to undertand :)

Comment: for me it looks like an encryption algorithm ...

Comment: Good one, @Kent :) I think it is pretty complex: given a word with an hyphen `-`, add the next word ending with closing parentheses `)`.

Comment: @fedorqui you even find the pattern! you the bloody hacker!!!

Comment: Hi was not the only one who did see the pattern ;) I just used some time to make a working script.

Comment: @Jotne you are hackers! I watched the text for a while, and gave up. but with your "decryption", I can write a little solution.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have understand the logic.
If a line has a `-` in it, get the field from next line that has a `)` in it.
Then remove the field form that line.

```
awk  '
    /-/ {
        a=$0
        getline
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~")") 
            t=i
        sub(/-/,"-"$t,a)
        $t=""
        print a "\n" $0
        next
    }
    !/-/' file

A B C D E
jeden dwa-czarny) trzy cztery piec
 bialy zielony niebieski siwy
czarny) bialy zielony niebieski siwy
kot pies mysz osa byk
jeblon grusza czeresnia-filolek) sliwa orzech
tulipan narcyz  irys bez
sliwka jabkko pomarancza kiwi arbuz
5 A B C D E
sliwka jabkko pomarancza kiwi arbuz-tomek)
marek ewa ela  romek
```

---

And for those who like one liners:

```
awk '/-/ {a=$0;getline;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~")")t=i;sub(/-/,"-"$t,a);$t="";print a "\n" $0;next} !/-/' file
```

---

Shorten it some by using split to find the word and no loop:

```
awk  -F")" '
    /-/ {
        a=$0
        getline
        t=split($1,x," ")
        sub(/-/,"-"x[t]")",a)
        $t=""
        print a "\n" $0
        next
    }
    !/-/
    ' file
```

```
awk  -F")" '/-/ {a=$0;getline;t=split($1,x," ");sub(/-/,"-"x[t]")",a);$t="";print a"\n"$0;next} !/-/' file
```

Comment: `czeresnia` should have `filolek` instead of `tulipan`. +1 for Polishing it :D

Comment: I do now this :) that is why I needed to polish it some.

Answer (score 6):

thanks @fedorqui's "decryption", I think that playing `RS` could make the problem easier to be solved. I come up with this one-liner: (it worked with my gawk)

```
awk -v RS='\\S+\\)' -v ORS="" '{$0=sub(/-/,"-"RT)?$0:$0RT}7' file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat f
A B C D E
jeden dwa- trzy cztery piec
czarny) bialy zielony niebieski siwy
czarny) bialy zielony niebieski siwy
kot pies mysz osa byk
jeblon grusza czeresnia- sliwa orzech
tulipan narcyz filolek) irys bez
sliwka jabkko pomarancza kiwi arbuz
5 A B C D E
sliwka jabkko pomarancza kiwi arbuz-
marek ewa ela tomek) romek

kent$  awk -v RS='\\S+\\)' -v ORS="" '{$0=sub(/-/,"-"RT)?$0:$0RT}7' f
A B C D E
jeden dwa-czarny) trzy cztery piec
 bialy zielony niebieski siwy
czarny) bialy zielony niebieski siwy
kot pies mysz osa byk
jeblon grusza czeresnia-filolek) sliwa orzech
tulipan narcyz  irys bez
sliwka jabkko pomarancza kiwi arbuz
5 A B C D E
sliwka jabkko pomarancza kiwi arbuz-tomek)
marek ewa ela  romek
```

Comment: Does not work on my Ubuntu Linux.  It does not move word from line below and up. And if you look at your solution, a word `trzy` from second line is gone.

Comment: @Jotne oh, yes, the sub() is eaiser, I update right now. it was tested with gawk